# Overloading operator= for char*

Tags: c++

Don't be hard with my first question here.

When I use char array this way:

1. `char s[50] = "Some string";`
   it's works.

But this way:

2)

```
char* s2 = new char[50];
s2 = "Another string";
```

Compiler doesn't agree to put `const char` to `char*`.

A know the way to do it right.
And I know how to use string also. But our teacher asks students to use in their homework `char*` only.

My Question is:

#### May I overload `operator=` for `char*`?

Because I asked this in my school and was told "NO" on this question.

But may be someone here help me to find 'How'
or at least to understand 'Why Not?'

Comment: Do you have the exact description of exercise you have to do?

Comment: even if it were allowed then `char* s2 = new char[50]; s2 = "Another string"` still leaks memory

Comment: #1 isn’t really doing what you think. It has fooled you into thinking that you can assign char * variables sometimes. You cannot, that’s what stripy is for. Or learn to use std::string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard does not allow you to overload operators where none of the operands have a class or enumeration type. Therefore, you cannot overload `operator=` for `char*` because it is prohibited by the C++ standard. Operator overloading does not allow you to override the behavior of the built-in operator.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the compiler is helping you prevent from accidentally modifying a string literal, which is a `const char*`.

You'll need to use `strcpy()` for this.

```
char *s = new char[50];
strcpy(s, "Another string");
// Modify s as you please here..
s[0] = 'a';
printf("%s\n", s); // prints 'another string'
```

```
char *x = "Hello, world!"; // Compiler error/warning is raised here, depending on its modernity
*x[0] = 'h'; // Try to change to 'hello, world!'
// Actual result: Segfault, Bus error, etc. (cannot change read-only memory)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to use strcpy. My question was more about 'Why not?'.

Comment: `char *` means the pointer is pointing to a mutable array of `char`s. A string literal is a `const char*`, which means any pointer pointing to it must not modify the contents as the results are undefined. Thus, the compiler prevents you from assigning a `const char*` to `char *` because this will allow you to modify that string literal, which is for all intents and purposes, read-only.

Comment: Mutable means that you can change a variable even through const method. Or not?

Comment: @NoOrdinaryLove -- be very careful here; arrays and pointers are not the same thing, although they often act like they are. `char*` is a pointer to **a** mutable `char`. That `char` might be part of an array, but it doesn't have to be. `char ch; char *s = &ch;`. A string literal is **not** a `const char*`. It's a `const char[N]`, where `N` is the number of characters in the literal plus one (for the nul terminator). This gets confusing because in most contexts, the **name** of an array **decays** into a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @BessieTheCow -- you can't modify a string literal, even with a const cast. It's a **const** object, so it can't be modified. Formally, the behavior is undefined; back in the olden days, string literals were placed in ordinary memory, and they could, in fact, be modified. These days they're mostly in read-only memory, and you can't change them.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's what I meant.

Comment: @BessieTheCow -- that's why you have to be very careful here. In particular, "the compiler won't allow you to assign [a string literal's] address to a non-const pointer because that would allow you to modify the string without an explicit const cast," is, at best, misleading. A const cast doesn't make modifying a string literal valid.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree that my comment is a bit misleading. I've deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload it. In the particular case, you need to call `strcpy()` (declared in the standard C++ header `cstring` or C header `string.h`). But note, this is C runtime function. Programming in "C like C++" is bad coding practice. Consider using `std::string` in C++.